# Creating an AlertDialog with a list

Tags: java, android, xml

I am wanting to implement an `AlertDialog` with a list into my app and I created a sample to see if I can get the result that I am looking for. It seems I do have the result I wanted but before I implement it into my actual app, is there a way to make my code better?:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                showAlertDialogWithList();
        }
    }

    public void showAlertDialogWithList() {
        List<String> mAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
        mAnimals.add("Cat");
        mAnimals.add("Dog");
        mAnimals.add("Horse");
        mAnimals.add("Elephant");
        mAnimals.add("Rat");
        mAnimals.add("Lion");
        mAnimals.add("Tiger");
        mAnimals.add("Bird");
        mAnimals.add("Zebra");
        mAnimals.add("Cheetah");
        mAnimals.add("Hyena");

        final CharSequence[] animals = mAnimals.toArray(new String[mAnimals.size()]);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Animals");
        dialogBuilder.setItems(animals, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                String selectedText = animals[i].toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialogObject.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many times you wish to use this on your project so I tested and I suggest you to first extract the list from the method context and receive it as argument.

```
public void showAlertDialogWithList(List<String> mAnimals) {

    final CharSequence[] animals = mAnimals.toArray(new String[mAnimals.size()]);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Animals");
    dialogBuilder.setItems(animals, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            String selectedText = animals[i].toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialogObject.show();
}
```

Then you can extract a class and put it in some util package making it available to entire project like this one:

```
public class AlertDialogList {
    public static void showAlertDialogWithList(String title, List<String> mAnimals, final Activity activity) {

        final CharSequence[] animals = mAnimals.toArray(new String[mAnimals.size()]);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
        dialogBuilder.setItems(animals, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                String selectedText = animals[i].toString();
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), selectedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialogObject.show();
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
 AlertDialogList.showAlertDialogWithList("Animals Title", this.animals, this);
```